# so as to + make(s)

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I found this sentence in an IELTS book and am questioning whether it is correct:

"It would be a good idea to ban cars from city centres on Sundays, so as to makes cities quieter and cleaner for people to walk around."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It should be 'so as to make', not 'make**s**'.

But if you're curious about the 'so as to make' part in general, in situations like this, 'so as' means something like 'the manner previously mentioned'.